# SQL QUERY obter Média de um mês de um relativo dia da semana

Tags: c#, sql, query

Necessito de uma query que me retorne a media de um relativo mês, e de uma dia da semana.
Por exemplo:
Preciso de saber os componentes relativos ao Mês de Fevereiro, do dia da semana Segunda-Feira.
É possível definir alguma expressão para o `DATA`, sendo que `DATA` é do tipo date no `sql`

```
SELECT AVG(P.Quant) AS Expr1
FROM     P
WHERE  (Pro.Tipo = 'B') AND (V.ID= 1)
AND (DATA =:....")
```

Comment: Você quer dizer "todas as segundas-feiras do mês de fevereiro"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quiser todas as segundas-feiras do mês de fevereiro, independente do ano, use:

```
SELECT AVG(P.Quant) AS Expr1
FROM     P
WHERE  (Pro.Tipo = 'B') AND (V.ID= 1)
AND EXTRACT(DOW FROM P.data) = 1
AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM P.data) = 2;
```

A função EXTRACT pode ter outro nome no SGBD que estiver utilizando.

Comment: Com Linq é possível utilizar o EXTRACT?

Comment: @user6018: Não conheço o Link mas no MS-SQL Server existe a função DATEPART com a mesma funcionalidade. technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258863(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho 50 pontos para comentar, mas poderia postar sua estrutura da tabela?!

```
SELECT avg(month(valor_do_mes)) as media_mes, avg(day(valor_do_dia)) as media_dia FROM tbl WHERE /*aí você pode converter para data e fazer o where*/ MONTH(campo) and DAY(dia)
```

Caso não dê certo, manda a estrutura da tua tabela!

Valeuu!

Comment: 10 pontinhos pra vc poder fazer comentários úteis